# Webview shows nothing when I put styles with color in head

Tags: android, react-native, webview

When I put the following CSS code as head of the source for my webview the webview shows nothing at all. I have made some testing. It works sometimes if I remove all attributes with constants from another file (if I remove ${theme.----}) and replace them with "red", replacing it with "#ffffff" doesn't work. I don't understand why webview cant handle hex-colorvalues. I have tried it with react-native ^2 ^3 and ^5 none worked. My code used to work fine and used to work with styling in head couldn't yet find what has changed.

```
import theme from './../../constants/theme';

CSS:`
<head>
<style>
body{
    padding-left:2%;
    width:92%;
    background-color: ${theme.background.primary};
    color:${theme.text.primary};
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-size: 1.05em;
}
img{
    height:auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px ${theme.background.primaryVariant};
}
iframe{
    height:auto;
    max-width:100%;
}
a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: ${themeDark.tertiary};
}
p{
    margin-top:0.2em;
    margin-bottom:0.2em;
}
</style>
</head>`
```

My webview:

```
var page = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/>
      `+css+`
        </head>
        <body>`+body+script;
```

---

```
{this.state.isLoadingWebview ? <ActivityIndicator size="large"/> : null}
<View style={{flex:1,opacity:this.state.isLoadingWebview ? 0:1,backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>     
    <ScrollView style={this.state.baseStyles.body} contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}>
        <WebView
        originWhitelist={null}
        style={styles.WebViewStyle}  
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        source={{ html: page}}
        ref={(ref) => { this.webview = ref; }}
        onNavigationStateChange={(event) => {
            //console.log(event);
            //console.log("Event URL"+event.url);
            this.onWebviewPressLink(event);
        }}
        cacheEnabled={true}
        onLoadEnd={()=>this.setState({isLoadingWebview:false})}
        />
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

My theming constants:

```
const theme = {
    primary:"#df691a",
    primaryVariant:"#a74f13",
    secondary:"#2b3e50",
    secondaryVariant:"#a74f13",
    tertiary:"#d1332e",
    etc...
}

export default theme;
```

Comment: Could you provide a full App.js so we can run it? You don't have to post your whole `<body>`.

Comment: @diogenesgg I have added some more context.

Comment: I feel your problem doesn't rely on the css code. How is your `ender()` method exactly? Find a way to export your final html code into a `.html` file so you can open it on a browser in order to validate it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old and OP may not need it anymore, but it may help someone else. For some reason WebView doesn't like the # in front of the hex value. With # removed it works, which is odd since it contradicts the spec.
EDIT: A better approach is probably to replace the `#` with `%23` which also works.